# How to get one of reverse foreign-key records when in a model queryset

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

I'm working on a django website for keeping track of devices in the network.

I have a model `Device`:

```
class DeviceManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return super().get_queryset().annotate(
            num_interfaces=Count('interface', distinct=True))

class Device(models.Model):
    objects = DeviceManager()
    uuid = models.UUIDField()
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)

    class Meta:
        _base_manager = DeviceManager()
```

and then I have model `Interface`:

```
from .models import Device

class Interface(models.Model):
    ip = models.GenericIPAddressField()
    device = models.ForeignKey(Device, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

When displaying a list of devices, I need to list the number of interfaces for each device. So I created the Manager which pulls the count with one query, instead of having a separate query for each device in the list.

Now I want to display a random IP for each device. It doesn't which one, if a device has multiple interfaces.

I started writing another `.annotate` to my `DeviceManger`and I am not sure what to do.

I was thinking about using a subquery, something like:

```
subquery = Interface.objects.filter(ip=OuterRef('ip'))
```

so:

```
class DeviceManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        subquery = Interface.objects.filter(device_id=OuterRef('device'))

        return super().get_queryset().annotate(
            num_interfaces=Count('interface', distinct=True)).annotate(
            ip=Coalesce(Min(Subquery(subquery('ip'))), None)
```

But then I realized that `Interface` depends on `Device`, and so I can't refer to `Interface` until `Device` is fully defined, so definitely not in `DeviceManager`

What is the best way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

You're pretty close. Though I don't recommend adding these methods to your manager's `get_queryset` method unless you literally need them for the vast majority of queries. Instead create a separate function or generate the querys as needed.

```
from django.db.models import OuterRef, Subquer
interfaces = Interface.objects.filter(device_id=OuterRef('id')).order_by('?')
Device.objects.annotate(
    num_interfaces=Count('interface', distinct=True),
    random_ip=Subquery(interfaces.values('ip')[:1]),
)
```